Drivers SQL Server para Lampp en Ubuntu 20.4.6
Quiero instalar los drivers pdo_sqlserver y sqlserver en Ubuntu pero en opt/lampp es la version 7.4 de php. Porque no me esta dejando hacer consultas a la base de datos y me falta la dependencia.
O sea basicamenete, instalo las dependencias en /opt/lampp/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/, las dos que necesito, las habilito en php.ini y sin embargo me sigue tirando el mismo error, esto me sucede solo en el servidor de ubuntu, en mi maquina local con xampp de windows no. EL error es el siguiente es mi apliacion cakephp: Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

Y cual es el problema?

O sea basicamenete, instalo las dependencias en /opt/lampp/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/, las dos que necesito, las habilito en php.ini y sin embargo me sigue tirando el mismo error, esto me sucede solo en el servidor de ubuntu, en mi maquina local con xampp de windows no. EL error es el siguiente es mi apliacion cakephp: Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

Toda esa informacion, debe ir en la pregunta.. como esperas que alguien te ayude si no aclaras todo lo que hiciste y probaste???
